# NSDictionay display

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdictionary

im not able to display the values from this code .plz provide a code to display the mutabledictionay and a

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     mdict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
     [mdict setValue:@"abc" forKey:@"def"];

     [mdict release];
}

-(void)display{

     CFShow(mdict);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using

```
-(void)display{

     NSLog(@"%@",mdict);

}
```

Change your method as:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     mdict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
     [mdict setValue:@"abc" forKey:@"def"];


     //if you want to display use following statement
     [self display];

    // [mdict release];//you should not release it here.
}
```

NOTE: In `viewDidLoad` you are using `[mdict release];`  mdict will be released!!!

this should not be in `viewDidLoad`, put that statement in `dealloc`.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to create `NSMutableDictionary` is **Public** (declare in .h file) because you use it in outside and release its instance in `dealloc` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     self.mdict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
     [self.mdict setValue:@"abc" forKey:@"def"];

     [self display];
}
-(void)display
{
   NSLog(@"%@",[self.mdict objectForKey:@"def"]);
}
```

and release instance of dictionary  in `-(void)dealloc` method

Comment: i have tried it but it is not working  can you give me other  alternative

Comment: y cont we use CFShow() insted of NSLog()?

Comment: because , u can display value without use of CFShow()

Comment: im not getting any error ..but displaying as def=abc is this corret

Comment: nor abc is value and def is kay of this value ,,,u can access value of dictionary using key